# WordPress: get all posts included in two taxonomies (WP_Query tax_query relation AND)

Tags: php, wordpress, function, taxonomy

Of course, this can be counted as a duplicate, but I can't beat this task in any way, I'm just learning)

There are several taxonomies, for example, `location` and `set`. I need to output the number of posts included in both taxonomies. My function now looks like this:

```php
function get_all_property_count($id, $setid)
{

    $count = new WP_Query(array(
        'nopaging' => true,
        'post_type' => 'property',
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'tax_query' => array(
            'relation' => 'OR',
            array(
                'taxonomy'          => 'location',
                'field'             => 'id',
                'fields'            => 'ids',
                'terms'             => $id,
            ),
            array(
                'relation' => 'AND',
                array(
                    'taxonomy'          => 'set',
                    'field'             => 'id',
                    'fields'            => 'ids',
                    'terms'             => $setid,
                    'include_children'  => true,
                )
            )
        ),
    ));
    return $count->post_count;
}
```

Then I use it to get a counter of posts published in the current taxonomy and another by id (I'm not sure if I'm explaining it correctly().

```php
<div class="count_property">
    <div class="sell">
        <span class="strong">Sell:</span> <?php echo get_all_property_count($term->term_id, 30); ?>
    </div>
    <div class="rent">
        <span class="strong">Rent:</span> <?php echo get_all_property_count($term->term_id, 31); ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

Where `$term->term_id`, category id from `location` taxonomy. `30` and `31` sale and rental categories from `set` taxonomy.

At the exit I get one more in `sell`. For example,`Sell: 2` (although there should be 0 in general), `Rent: 1` (that's right).

Comment: And how you get $id, $setid ? $setid should hold always 30 and 31 right ? So you want if you are currently on Location A to check how many properties are for rent and for sell for this location ?

Comment: Right. $id we get the from the current location - gives the correct value. $setid = 30 or 31. There will be other $setids, but I check them and something goes wrong)

Answer (score 0):

Try the following solution

```
function get_post_count_by_term_slug($post_type,$taxonomy,$term_slug) {
    $current_obj = get_queried_object();
    // Check if we are on specific taxonomy page like location
    if(!is_tax('location')) return;    

    $args = array(
        'post_type' => $post_type,
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'tax_query' => array(
            'relation' => 'AND',
            array(
                'taxonomy' => $current_obj->taxonomy, // Here we get current location
                'field' => 'id',
                'terms' => $current_obj->term_id
            ),
            array(
            'taxonomy' => $taxonomy,
            'field' => 'slug',
            'terms' => $term_slug
            )
        ),
    );
    $count = new WP_Query($args);
    if($count->have_posts()):
        echo $count->post_count;
    else: 
        echo 'Nothing found';
    endif;
}

// Use it like this get_post_count_by_term_slug('post_type','taxonomy_name','tax_term_slug');

<div class="count_property">
    <div class="sell">
        <span class="strong">Sell:</span> <?php get_post_count_by_term_slug('property','set','sell'); ?>
    </div>
    <div class="rent">
        <span class="strong">Rent:</span> <?php get_post_count_by_term_slug('property','set','rent'); ?>
    </div>
</div>
```